# ExtJS: Attach Ext events to component before it exists

Tags: javascript, events, extjs

Let's say I have a component, and this component needs to add an event listener to a component that does NOT exist yet, but will. Let's say it needs to for the 'beforerender' event of this yet-to-be-created component.

As it is right now, without knowing how to do this in ExtJS, I would do something like this:

```
var wait = setInterval(function() {
    var cmp = Ext.getCmp('myThing');

    if (cmp) {
        clearInterval(wait);
        cmp.on('beforerender', function() {
            // ... do something on render
        });
    }
}, 20);
```

How would I do this in Ext?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer in some random github repository this morning:

https://github.com/prettycode/Ext.exts/blob/master/Ext.latentEvent.js

Apparently, there's a `onAvailable` event that `Ext.ComponentManager` exposes. When a component is created, it makes its way through `Ext.ComponentManager`, and `onAvailable` will let listeners know after given components have been added.

Answer (score 1):

There is a config called "listeners" which does exactly this:

```
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    title: 'myPanel',
    ....
    listeners: {
        'beforerender': function(panel, a, b) {
         ....
         }
    }
});
```

Comment: Hmm, I think you're missing the point a little. My apologies for not being clearer. A component on the page needs to listen to an event for a *different* component, that has not yet been created. :)